# Node running a different React application when using "npm run start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost, web-development-server

I was developing a different app titled "Video Chat" around 5-6 hours ago and after my work was done I switched over to a different app and ran it using the "npm start" command, however the command now only starts the "Video Chat" app in the localhost and I'm stuck here. Any suggestions? Both applications were created using ReactJS.

The problem persists even after I've deleted the "Video Chat" application, reinstalled Node LTS version and even changed the partitions of the project I'm working on now. I want to run my current application on the localhost for development.

Answer (score 0):

`npm start` depends upon what is written under package.json file on **start** property on **script**s object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to task manager and stop the node engine. And start your application in a new terminal. It always happens due to the cashes of the current engine. Once you stopped the node in the background process, it will load your command next time in a new node engine.